# Different certificate templates on different CAs with same user - Microsoft ADCS

Tags: active-directory, x509certificate, pki, gpo

I am facing a serious trouble regarding certificate autoenrollment using CES-CEP for AD users.

Let's consider a domain called COMPANY.CORP, in which there are deployed all PKI services (2-tier Enterprise PKI with 1 Root and 2 SubCAs, OCSP and 2 CES-CEP services -one per SubCA), and another domain called OFFICE.CORP that has a selective-CFT with the COMPANY.CORP domain.

Users from OFFICE.CORP domain need a digital certificate FROM COMPANY.CORP to log into several business apps from OFFICE.CORP. There are two types of machines that can be used by all users: their own workstation and some "public" spots in which they can login as well (in which local profiles are deleted daily).

It is required that when an user from this OFFICE.CORP logs into their workstation, a certificate from a template 'A' (1-year lifetime) has to be issued. Otherwise, a certificate from a template 'B' (1-day lifetime) has to be issued.

Some diagram about the scenario:
[image: Case-scenario diagram]

Workstations and public spots are splitted into two different OUs.

Is it even possible to do so using some kind of GPO filtering at the user side? AFAIK, Users GPOs are unique and cannot be filtered depending on where the user has logged into.

Wished goal would be:

- GPO A: only applied when the user logs into its own workstation, allows Autoenrollment over template A (issued by CA1 through CES-CEP1)
- GPO B: only applied when the user logs into any other machine (such as these public spots), allowing the Autoenrollment over template B (CES-CEP2 and CA2)
- Both GPOs can not be ran at the same time

Thanks everyone!

Edit: I have just read it again some time later and I noticed that some info could lead to a mistake, so I have edited it clarifying some points.

Comment: Please check this it may help you : https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/certificate-autoenrollment-in-windows-server-2016-part-3.aspx

Comment: Hello @rafaelrroa, If my answer is helpful for you, you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to Autoenrollment configuration policy using GPO features.

Autoenrollment configuration in general consist of three steps: configure autoenrollment policy, prepare certificate templates and prepare certificate issuers. The recommended way to configure autoenrollment policy is to use Group Policy feature. Group policy feature is available in both, domain, and workgroups environments. It is recommended to turn on autoenrollment policy in both, user, and computer configuration.

Would suggest you to refer this [Document 1](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/enabling-cep-and-ces-for-enrolling-non-domain-joined-computers/ba-p/397821) and [Document 2](https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/certificate-autoenrollment-in-windows-server-2016-part-3.aspx) Creating a new template for the autoenrollment and Enabling CEP and CES for enrolling non-domain joined computers for certificate

Comment: Thank you for your answer @RahulKumarShaw-MT, but although you are right on it, it does not fully cover my needs. I have updated my question with some new info, hoping you can still help me :)